keycloak user storage SPI by client
In a keycloak, I recently set up keycloak User storage SPI. My need was to connect a specific client on keycloak to an external database that I maintain. This works very well. The problem I encounter is that since the SPI is configured on the Realm, all clients have access. This implies that if I try to connect with another client, it will have access to this data source, which of course I do not want.
I thought it was possible to filter this provider in a custom browser flow, but after many searches in this direction I found nothing.
So my question is: Is it possible to configure User storage SPI for a single client? If not, what alternatives besides filtering on a role, which would be done after querying the SPI.
